# List.fold_left applied only with one argument

Tags: ocaml

I don't understand the following code :

```
type 'a b_tree = Empty | Node of 'a*'a b_tree*'a b_tree


  let add_trees_with left right all =
    let add_right_tree all l =
      List.fold_left (fun a r -> Node('x', l, r) :: a) all right in
    List.fold_left add_right_tree all left
```

I don't understand what comes after the `in` part. `List.fold_left` need to have three argument whereas after the `in` we only give one argument to the `List.fold_left` which is `add_right_tree all left`.

So How can this code compile ?

Shouldn't it be ?

```
type 'a b_tree = Empty | Node of 'a*'a b_tree*'a b_tree


  let add_trees_with left right all =
    let add_right_tree all l =
      List.fold_left (fun a r -> Node('x', l, r) :: a) all right in
    add_right_tree all left
```

Comment: I would have helped you, but you'll probably just delete the question while I'm in the middle of writing a sentence, like you usually do, so I don't see why I should bother. But here's a hint: What's the type of `List.fold_left`? More specifically the first argument.

Comment: @glennsl I am really sorry for the other question. But I understood your comment and spotted the stupid mistake, that's why I deleted. It won't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
List.fold_left add_right_tree all left
```

There are three arguments to the function `List.fold_left`. Function calls are left associative, so the parenthesized version would be this:

```
((List.fold_left add_right_tree) all) left
```

Because List.fold_left is defined in curried form, this is exactly the way to pass three arguments.

The parenthesization does *not* look like this:

```
List.fold_left ((add_right_tree all) left) (* NOT SO *)
```

Note that this interpretation isn't even consistent. It's neither left associative nor right associative. But this is the intepretation you are assuming.